# How can I verify that h1 tag has a specific text using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I verify that some element has a specific attribute value using Selenium IDE?
For example - If we have `div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"` how can I verify that the current element has an id equal to `fb-root`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `verifyAttribute`.

Usage:

```
verifyAttribute  |  css=div.fb_reset@id  |  fb-root
```

Comment: But your example is for locating some element in the current page with div#fb-root. My idea is to verify that a div element has a specific attribute. For example - how can I prove that the particular div has a id="fb-root". Or with pseudo code it will look like this : if( specific div has a id==my value) then true / else false

Comment: edited.  the testing logic is the same, but if you want specificity at the level you want, then my edit should be what you want.

Comment: Okay, so how can I verify that heading h1>Example</h1> has an "Example" as a text value?

Comment: `verifyText  |  css=h1  |  Example`  - however this will fail if there are more `h1`'s on the page.

Comment: go ahead and upvote / accept the question if it was helpful to you :)  glad i could help.